# Laravel migration inheritance is not working

Tags: php, database, laravel, migration, php-7

I'm new to Laravel and php so I face and error I don't know how to solve.

The basic problem is since a lot of tables have `primary:id` and `created_by,updated_by` columns what I've figured out is inheriting them in my migrations.

I'm using php7

So I have a Base class

```
class BaseMigration extends Migration {

  public function up(string $tableName) {
    Schema::create($tableName, function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->mediumIncrements('id');
      $table->primary('id');

      $table->unsignedMediumInteger('created_by')->references('id')->on('users');
      $table->unsignedMediumInteger('updated_by')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
  }
}
```

and the extending migration

```
class CreateItemsTable extends BaseMigration {

    public function up() {
        parent::up('items');

        Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {

          $table->string('name', 74);
          $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    // ......
}
```

However `php artisan migrate` gives me this:

`[ErrorException] Declaration of CreateItemsTable::up() should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Migrations\BaseMigration::up(string $tableName)`

Is it because I'm running double `up()` ?

What am I missing? Appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to have the same function signature, so pass `string $tableName`:

```
class CreateItemsTable extends BaseMigration {

    public function up(string $tableName) {
        Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
          parent::up('items');

          $table->string('name', 74);
          $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    // ......
}
```